# For infinitely many $A_{\alpha}$, $\cup_{\alpha}\overline{A_{\alpha}}\subset \overline{\cup_{\alpha}A_{\alpha}}$ - don't understand proof

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

I am aware of the classic counter example of $\displaystyle \cup_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[0, 1-\frac{1}{n}\right]$ for why the infinite union of closed sets is not necessarily closed. The reason why this example fails is because $[0,1]\not\subset [0,1)$.

My book says, however, that it is always true that for all sets $A_{\alpha}$, $\cup_{\alpha}\overline{A_{\alpha}}\subset \overline{\cup_{\alpha}A_{\alpha}}$; however, I don't understand their proof.

They say that it follows from the fact that $A_{\alpha} \subset \displaystyle \cup_{\alpha}A_{\alpha} \subset \overline{\cup_{\alpha}A_{\alpha}}$ coupled with the facts that (1) For sets $A$ and $B$, $A \subset B$ $\implies$ $\overline{A}\subset \overline{B}$; and (2) $\overline{\overline{A}}=\overline{A}$ (that is, $\overline{A}$ is closed). But, I don't see how those things work together to show this.

All I get from those statements together is that $\overline{A_{\alpha}} \subset \overline{\displaystyle \cup_{\alpha}A_{\alpha}}$. I don't see how just those things allow us to conclude that $\cup_{\alpha}\overline{A_{\alpha}}\subset \overline{\cup_{\alpha}A_{\alpha}}$; **could somebody please explain this to me?**

If I were to prove that $\cup_{\alpha}\overline{A_{\alpha}}\subset \overline{\cup_{\alpha}A_{\alpha}}$, I would do it in the following way: Suppose $x\in \cup_{\alpha}\overline{A_{\alpha}}$. Then, $x$ is in at least one of the $\overline{A_{\alpha}}$, call it $\displaystyle\overline{A_{\alpha_{\displaystyle *}}}$. Now. $x \in \displaystyle\overline{A_{\alpha_{\displaystyle *}}}$ means that $\exists$ a neighborhood $U(x)$ of $x$ such that $U(x) \cap A_{\alpha_{\displaystyle *}} \neq \emptyset$ So, $\displaystyle \cup_{\alpha} (U(x) \cap A_{\alpha}) \neq \emptyset$. By the Distributive Laws for sets, this means that $U(x) \cap (\displaystyle \cup_{\alpha}A_{\alpha})\neq \emptyset$ For some neighborhood $U(x)$ of $x$. So, $x \in \overline{\cup_{\alpha}A_{\alpha}}$. **This is how it would have occurred to me at first blush to prove it. Is this proof correct? If not, is it fixable, or should I stick to the book's way (once you've explained it to me, of course)?**

Thank you ahead of time.

Comment: If $A_{\alpha}\subset B$ for all $\alpha$, then $\bigcup_{\alpha}A_{\alpha}\subset B$.

Comment: @RenanManeliMezabarba ugh. That is so silly of me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed for each fixed $\beta \in A$:

$$A_\beta \subset \cup_{\alpha \in A} A_\alpha \subseteq \overline{ \cup_{\alpha \in A} A_\alpha}$$, so

$$\overline{A_\beta}  \subseteq \overline{\overline{ \cup_{\alpha \in A} A_\alpha}} = \overline{\cup_{\alpha \in A} A_\alpha}$$

As this holds for all indices $\beta \in A$, their union is a subset of that fixed set too: $\cup_{\alpha \in A} \overline{A_\alpha} \subseteq \overline{\cup_{\alpha \in A} A_\alpha}$ as required.

A standard inclusion argument also works but needs to be fixed (not "there is a neighbourhood that intersects the set", but *every* neighbourhood does):

Suppose $x \in \cup_{\alpha \in A} \overline{A_\alpha}$, and we want to 
$x \in \overline{\cup_{\alpha \in A} A_\alpha}$. To this end let $U$ be any open neighbourhood of $x$. We know that $x \in \overline{A_{\beta}}$ for some $\beta \in A$. So by the definition of closure: $U \cap A_\beta \neq \emptyset$, but any point in that intersection also lies in $\cup_{\alpha \in A} A_\alpha$.
So $U$ always intersects $\cup_{\alpha \in A} A_\alpha$, for any $U$, so $x \in \overline{\cup_{\alpha \in A} A_\alpha}$.

Comment: @HenroBrandsma can you please take a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2179730/strongly-equivalent-metrics-induce-equivalent-topologies-trouble-with-radii-of ? I'm stuck and I'm having trouble figuring out how to move forward from there. Thank you! :)